# iOS Asynchronous Unit Testing (waitForExpectations failing) in Xcode 8 / Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, xctest

I'm updating my Cocoapod that I developed to use Swift 3. Before I upgraded, all of my asynchronous unit tests were working perfectly fine. But now after upgrading, every single one of them immediately fail and I have no idea why. Here is what each one is structured like:

```
override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        validationExpectation = expectation(description: "Validation")
}

.
.
.

func testSymbolRequest(){

        _ = MyCocoapod.makeSymbolRequest(symbol: "ABC", success: { (symbolObject) in
            self.validationExpectation.fulfill()
            XCTAssert(true)
        }) { (error) in
            self.validationExpectation.fulfill()
            XCTFail(error.description)
        }

        waitForRequestToFinish()
}

.
.
.

func waitForRequestToFinish(){
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 60.0) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            XCTFail(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

The waitForExpectations function isn't waiting at all. It immediately fails after being called. I have also confirmed that is has nothing to do with my actual networking code and the requests work perfectly fine in my Cocoapod example project. I'm using Alamofire. I don't think that's the problem but I thought it might be worth mentioning. The error message that is printed out is "unknown error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to test your CocoaPod that you are developing, for some reason, the default testing target that it creates makes the waitForExpectations() function not work properly for that particular testing target. I was able to get it to finally work by doing these steps in order:

1. Delete the current testing target
2. Create a new testing target
3. Run a pod install and make sure the pod file is updated accordingly

Following these steps, I was able to get the waitForExpectations() to finally work within my network requests.